# Count groups in loop foreach

Tags: php, foreach, count

**My Script :**

```
<?php
$values='Product1,54,3,888888l,Product2,54,3,888888l,';
$exp_string=explode(",",$values);


$f=0;

foreach($exp_string as $exp_strings)
{

echo "".$f." - ".$exp_string[$f]."  ";

if ($f%3==0)
{
print "<br><hr><br>";
}


$f++;
}
?>
```

With this code i want show data inside loop, the idea it´s show all information in groups the elements in each group it´s 4 elements and must show as this :

**Results :**

**Group 1 :**

```
Product1,54€,3,green
```

**Group 2:**

```
Product2,56€,12,red
```

The problem it´s i don´t know why, don´t show as i want, and for example show separate some elements and not in group, thank´s , regards

Comment: in this case you better to use for rather than foreach and what is your input array ?

Comment: Can you post a sample of $exp_strings. At the present your code is a mess impossible to redeem, maybe with a little more data someone can sort it out.

Comment: And why put me negative ?, i don´t understand this website, where are people moderate this kind of people trolls, it´s incredible, you put here simple quetions and receive all kind of bad words, negatives, etc, what happend here in this website, where are please the people moderate this, this it´s international website, no only for people from usa or UK, or other countries, why never moderator do something for don´t let this situations, it´s incredible, really incredible, go here for learn about issue in php or other things and share, and receive this kind of things each time

Comment: Negative but answers NEVER

Comment: is this '888888l' a color?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to combine elements of a `for` loop and a `foreach` loop.

Here is an example of each, pulled from the php manual:

**[For Loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)**

```
for($index = 0, $index < size($array), $index++ {
  //Run Code
  //retrieve elements from $array with $array[$index]
}
```

**[Foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)**

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
foreach ($arr as &$value) {
    $value = $value * 2;
}
```

It's hard for me to understand what your input looks like. If you post an example of `$exp_strings`, I could be of better assistance. But from the sound of your question, if `$exp_strings` is multidimensional if you need to loop through groups of items, you could try nesting one loop inside another loop like so:

```
$groups_of_data = array(array(...), array(...), array(...));

for($i = 0, $i < size($groups_of_data), $i++) {
    $group = $i;
    for($j = 0, $j < size($groups_of_data[$i]), $j++) {
         // print out data related to group $i
    }  
}
```

This is really all guesswork on my part though as I can't see what your input string/array is. Can you post that? Maybe I can be of more help.

Comment: It´s easy in loop foreach, each 4 elements break and continue, for show large string of data each 4 elements, because the data string use data separated by ","

Comment: @Anton It sounds like there's probably a better way to parse the string. Perhaps take a look at the `explode()` [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: If you found my answer helpful at all, could please upvote? If not, maybe I can improve it for you?

Answer (score 0):

here is code i  worked out. it was kind of since i did't know what object  $exp_string is. if it's a string you should tokenize it, but i think it's array from database. there was another problem, with your code where it tries to output $exp_string[$f] it should be $exp_strings what changes in the loop.
my code

```
$exp_string=array("Product"=>54,"price"=>3,"color"=>"green");
$f=0;

foreach($exp_string as $key => $exp_strings)
{
if($f%3==0)
{
print "<br><hr><br>";
echo "Product ".$exp_strings."<br> ";
} 
  else  if($f%3==1)
{
echo "Price ".$exp_strings."<br> ";
}
 else if($f%3==2)
{
echo "Color ".$exp_strings."<br> ";
}

  $f++;
}
```

hope it's any help, maybe not what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
$values='Product1,1,2,3,Product2,1,2,3,Product3,1,2,3';

$products = (function($values) {
  $exp_string = explode(',', $values);
  $products = [];

  for ($i=0; $i+3<count($exp_string); $i+=4) {
    $product = [
      'title' => $exp_string[$i],
      'price' => $exp_string[$i+1],
      'color' => $exp_string[$i+2],
      'num' => $exp_string[$i+3],
    ];
    array_push($products, $product);
  }

  return $products;
})($values);

/* var_dump($products); */

foreach($products as $product) {
  echo "{$product['title']},{$product['price']},{$product['color']},{$product['num']}<br>";
}
```